# C# Create txt file and save

Tags: c#, forms, file, save

I am trying to create a file and save text, but it's only creating file can anyone suggest what the problem is?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
        sfd.FileName = "Password";
        sfd.Title = "Save Text File";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = sfd.FileName;
            StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path));
            bw.Write(randomstring);
            bw.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a file or append to file if one already exists ?

Comment: Habib, I and creating new and replace axisting one.

Comment: Grant, randomstring first i show it in label.text then i trying to save.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `bw.Close()` before calling `bw.Dispose()`. Per the API: "You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out to the underlying stream." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'd actually change the code to:

```
using (StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path)))
{
    bw.Write(randomstring);
    bw.Close();
}
```

The `using` block will automatically call `Dispose()`, whether or not everything completes successfully.

Comment: I don't see any reason to call close since Dispose is equal to close

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it is?

Comment: Reflector is your friend :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: they're not the same according to that API link I posted.

Comment: That link doesn't state both are different anywhere. FYI take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1187728/2530848)

Answer (score 2):

Try and use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

```
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //...
        File.WriteAllText(path, randomstring);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bw.Write(randomstring);
bw.Dispose();
```

You write something, then dispose of the object entirely. Try:

```
bw.Write(randomstring);
bw.Close();
bw.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to call `bw.Close()` before you dispose of it. Also, you should use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure that all `IDisposable`s are properly disposed of.

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = sfd.FileName;
    using (var fs = File.Create(path))
    using (StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        bw.Write(randomstring);
        bw.Close();
    }
}
```

Or just use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = sfd.FileName;
    File.WriteAllText(path, randomstring);
}
```