# File locked by another process even with using statement

Tags: c#, stream, streamwriter

I'm trying to write to a file called `output.txt`. It's fine the first time my code runs but the second time it throws an exception:

> The process cannot access output1.txt because it is being used by another process

But I'm using this in a `using` statement, and it should be disposed of and the file should be unlocked.

The constructor says `if the file exists, it can either be appended to or overwritten`. Doesn't seem to be doing this because of the IOException it is throwing.

Why is this happening?

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@directoryURL + "\\output"+outputNumber+".txt", true))
{
    foreach (string line in splitOutput)
    {
        file.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure that you application process is not still running in the background. If the process is still running kill it. If that doesn't work, try restarting.

Comment: The file is not open anywhere.

Comment: I mean the program that is reading it. Sometimes, when closed incorrectly, the process may stay behind.

Comment: related: [Does disposing a StreamWriter close the underlying Stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187700/does-disposing-a-streamwriter-close-the-underlying-stream)

Comment: The stream should close after the using statement anyway. I've tried to add a `file.Dispose()` in there but problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why a file can still be locked, e.g. virus scanners.

Use [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), "Find Handle" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), enter your file name and see which application has your file in use.

You have identified `urltest.vshost.exe` as the culprit (mentioned in a comment), so it must be your code...

In the code provided via PasteBin, I see the following loop

```
foreach (string file in fileEntries)
{
    StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(file);
    ...
    FileHander(fileStream, extension, websiteURL, fileName);
}
```

This opens many file streams, but `FileHandler()` only operates on certain extensions:

```
private void FileHander(StreamReader fileStream, string extension, string websiteURL, string fileName)
{
    switch (extension)
    {
        ...
        CheckPowershell(fileStream, websiteURL, fileName);
        ...
    }
}
```

And only `CheckPowershell()` closes the files:

```
private void CheckPowershell(StreamReader fileStream, string websiteURL, string fileName)
{
    ...
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

So all files which do not have a specific extension (such as `.txt`) remain open.

A quick solution seems to move the `Close()` from `CheckPowershell()` to `FileHander()`. A more professional way would need more refactoring.

Comment: I've used that and `urltest.vshost.exe` is locked the file. Which seems to be the GUI in which my code is running in.

Comment: I have a `StreamReader` in an earlier function which is in a `using` statement. This is the only `StreamWriter` I have in my code.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, this made a lot of sense.