# Is this possible somehow in C# : if (a==b==c==d) {...}

Tags: c#, comparison, operators, equality

Is there a quick way to compare equality of more than one values in C#?

```
something like:

if (5==6==2==2){

//do something

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public static class Common {
    public static bool AllAreEqual<T>(params T[] args)
    {
        if (args != null && args.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (args[i] != args[i - 1]) return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    } 
}

...

if (Common.AllAreEqual<int>(a, b, c, d, e, f, g))
```

This could help :)

Comment: In the `if`, I would use `!args[i].Equals(args[i - 1])`.  This allows use of reference types that implement `IEqualityComparer`.  By default `==` compares for reference equality on ref types, not its underlying value.

Answer (score 31):

```
if (a == b && b == c && c == d) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: 13 upvotes in 52 minutes? It's in fact the easy questions that bring the rep.

Comment: And the short concise answers? :-)

Comment: @Joachim: Don't tell me that you needed 24k rep to realize that ... ^^

Comment: @tanascius: of course I've had my suspicion, but this simply was an impressive demonstration of the fact. I've written more than a few answers that I felt were very good and thorough and got me only one or two upvotes.

Comment: Yes, I still find it amazing myself that my simplest answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222831/when-is-a-class-too-long/2222856#2222856) sometimes get a very high rating, while the answers on specialized subjects (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677652/using-using-to-dispose-of-nested-objects/2678242#2678242, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266168/ms-validation-block-or-workflow-rules-engine/2273940#2273940) get almost no rating. Popular subjects get higher rating easily.

Comment: My guess is that people that cannot understand the specialized subjects you refer to simply do not vote.

Answer (score 16):

In C#, an equality operator (`==`) evaluates to a `bool` so `5 == 6` evaluates to `false`.

The comparison `5 == 6 == 2 == 2` would translate to

```
(((5 == 6) == 2) == 2)
```

which evaluates to

```
((false == 2) == 2)
```

which would try to compare a `bool`with an `int`. Only if you would compare boolean values this way would the syntax be valid, but probably not do what you want.

The way to do multiple comparison is what @Joachim Sauer suggested:

```
 a == b && b == c && c == d
```

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible, you have to split it into separate statements.

```
if(x == y && x == z) // now y == z
{
}
```

Good luck