# StreamReader ReadLine is modifying / not releasing a Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, io, stream

I am using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) to parse CSV files uploaded on an ASP.NET app.

Two different CSV file structures (ie. different amount of columns) will be uploaded, so before I create the FileHelpers engine with the model of the structure to be parsed, I read the first line of the file like this:

```
string line = "";

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}

int fieldCount = line.Count(l => l == ',');
```

This works, and gives me the column count, but it breaks anything else I want to do with `file.InputStream`:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<CSVModel>();
CSVModel[] records;
records = (CSVModel[])engine.ReadStream(new StreamReader(file.InputStream),
    Int32.MaxValue);
// etc etc
```

Why does this happen? I've tried to take away the `using` and just manually close() the StreamReader but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is because the built in Stream classes dispose the underlying stream once they themselves are disposed or closed.

As counter-intuitive as it is, you'll either need to not close the stream if you're still using it, re-open it before accessing it, or copy it into a MemorStream if you want to use it in more than one place.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065168/does-disposing-streamreader-close-the-stream) has some explanations.

Edit: (After Jim's comment)

Alternatively you can inform the StreamReader not to close the underlying stream by using a parameter in the constructor. ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952.aspx))

Comment: In .NET 4.5 there's a [constructor that lets you tell it to leave the underlying stream open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952.aspx).

Comment: Wow, thanks for that @JimMischel. I'll update my answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the position of the stream after the first read:

```
file.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: That will not work. `StreamReader` has an internal buffer. So if you reset the underlying stream's position, things will get all jumbled the next time the `StreamReader` goes to update its buffer.