# Does "using" also dispose objects created in the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using-statement

When creating an element that implements `IDisposable`, `Dispose()` is called at the end of the `using` block also if an exception is thrown, if I'm correct.

However, when creating a new element of `ClassB` within the constructor of a disposable element, **will the object of ClassB also be disposed if `IDisposable` is implemented?**

```
using (ClassA a = new ClassA(new ClassB()))
{
}
```

This may apply to classes that are related to `Stream`. **However, does this apply in general?**

Comment: No. Its is not created within the constructor, but **before** the constructor.

Comment: It would be messed up if it did.  You could create a ClassB that implement IDisposable and test with about as many key strokes as this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ClassB` would only be disposed *if* the dispose method of `ClassA` calls dispose on it.

```
class ClassA : IDisposable
{
    private ClassB b;
    public ClassA (ClassB b) { this.b = b; }
    public void Dispose() { this.b.Dispose(); }
}
```

If it doesn't you'll need to dispose of it separately:

```
using (ClassB b = new ClassB())
using (ClassA a = new ClassA(b))
{
}
```

Comment: Even in the first case an exception in the `ClassA` constructor would result in leaking the `ClassB` instance.

Comment: So better not trust any class... Is there any way of finding out if a class also disposes of its constructor parameters other than decompiling? Streams seem to do that. But is there a general pattern?

Comment: @bytecode77 If it's documented as disposing of the resource, assume it will dispose of it.  If it doesn't explicitly state that it does, assume it doesn't.

Comment: @bytecode77, it is actually not a good practice to dispose injected objects. The example 1 in this answer is a bad decision. What if a `ClassB` object is shared among many `ClassA` instances?

Comment: It *should* be safe to call Dispose multiple times so even if `ClassA` did dispose of `ClassB`, if you used the second example it shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: But then the `ClassB` object is in a disposed state, and when another `ClassA`object tries to use it, we get for example an `ObjectDisposedException` or the object won't work as expected, depending on implementation.

Comment: @dymanoid - (first comment) not necessarily, there are occasions where you might need to do that (e.g. if you have a factory method which returns an `IThing` but the `Thing` implementation needs some other resource which is `IDisposable`)
(second comment) - that is true, this isn't supposed to be code review though, I'm simply answering the question of when `ClassB` would get disposed...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065196/1997232) is an example of first scenario (somewhat). You simply should know what will happens with object once you pass it to other object.

Comment: @dymanoid: If the last user of an object that wraps a resource will know nothing about the resource in question, the wrapper will likely be the only thing that *can* dispose the resource.  If a wrapper may be used with either shared or unshared resources, its constructor should allow the supplier of the resource to indicate whether the new object should take ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. If `ClassB` implements `IDisposable`, you should wrap it in a using block too:

```
using (var b = new ClassB())
using (var a = new ClassA(b))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Keep in mind that everything you pass to a constructor, or any other method which accepts parameters is evaluated **before** the constructor or method is invoked.

Some classes, like `StreamWriter` does with a `Stream`, will dispose whatever is passed through the constructor, but it's common to leave the disposing to whoever actually instantiated the object.