# StreamReader file can't be accessed

Tags: c#

The file can't be accessed because its being used by another process. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work, the error says problem is here in line 61. I can even locate the file and I have searched all the internet and can't find any help.

```
public class CalendarEntries : List<ICalendarEntry>
 {
    string calendarEntriesFile;
    public bool Load(string calendarEntriesFile)
    {
        bool status = true;
        this.calendarEntriesFile = calendarEntriesFile; //store path for future use

        if (!File.Exists(calendarEntriesFile))
        {
            status = false;
            File.Create(calendarEntriesFile); //create the file as it do not exists
        }
        else
            FillList(); // File exists! :) then what are we waiting for lets read it .  .

        return status;
    }

    private void FillList()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(calendarEntriesFile);
            string line = rd.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)// read line by line in file all apointments
            {
                string[] data = line.Split('#');
                Row row = new Row();
                row.Adopt(data);//create a row of current line i.e appointment
                this.Add(row); // add it to the current list for display
                line = rd.ReadLine();
            }
            rd.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured while reading the appointments File!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public bool Save(string[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            string line = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                line += data[i] + "#";
            }
            line = line.Remove(line.Length - 1);

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(calendarEntriesFile, true);
            writer.WriteLine(line);
            writer.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well yes - so what other process is accessing it? Fundamentally unless you work hard specifying the right file share mode everywhere you *won't* be able to get multiple processes accessing the same file at the same time. It's generally simpler just to make sure that they don't even try.

Comment: i dont know what process is accessing it, it was working fine before but i dont kno what happened

Comment: how can i fix this??

Comment: Do you mean that there should not be any other process accessing this file?  But you are still getting this message?

Comment: when i run it it doesnt read the file

Comment: what could be the problem

Comment: You will need to give more detail.  It is kind of hard to help someone debug a problem by looking at only one line of code.

Comment: i dont understand whats the problem?? it says the file cant be accessed because its used another processes

Comment: I would not be surprised if it is your own code that keeps the file locked. Do you use that file before this line? Please add more context (code) at your question.

Comment: i have now added more

Comment: help pls im struggliing

Comment: Close your streams in finally block since you may get exceptions. Put rd.close() and writer.close() in finally block after catch

Comment: where? can you post it

Comment: For example in FileList function : catch{...} finally{ rd.close();} . The safest way to close streams is in finally block.

Comment: i dont get what u mean???

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose of the streamreader.  Try using

```
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(calendarEntriesFile))
{
        string line = rd.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)// read line by line in file all apointments
        {
            string[] data = line.Split('#');
            Row row = new Row();
            row.Adopt(data);//create a row of current line i.e appointment
            this.Add(row); // add it to the current list for display
            line = rd.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

That will actually close and dispose of the streamreader.  You never dispose of it, so a reference to that reader is still out there.

Comment: now i've got a different error saying array was outside of boundary

Comment: So this solved the problem you had with the file.  A StreamReader is not disposed of if you just let it get garbage collected.  See @JonSkeet answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065196/4843530

Comment: i am not going to debug your entire program for you.  Your question is answered.  You should mark it so, and post a different question if you have something else you need help with.  **But** you should make every effort to debug the rest of your program before you ask for help here.

Comment: Date = DateTime.Parse(line[4);

Comment: help pls Agapwlesu

Answer (score 0):

CNuts answer ought to solve the problem. Try wrapping each stream into a using statement together with what CNuts suggested.

If it doesnt work despite this then you have to debug your code step by step tracing all the variable values in runtime.

When does it crash? After when your code creates the file or with already existing files too? That will define the solution.

Comment: existing files i think

Comment: array is outside boundaries

Comment: Date = DateTime.Parse(line[4]);

Comment: Then you are outside of the maximum length of the array. You have to debug your code. You just miscalculated something. Maybe the array just not filled up correctly.

Comment: when i change it from 0 to 4 it runs but doesnt work as i want it to

Comment: Variable line is a string isnt it? You are just parsing a char to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

If your error is " file cant be accessed because its being used by another process", You need to close if after creation.It is because you are appending data to file, not replacing the whole contents of file.

Also, based on @AgapwIesu answer, you need to dispose both StreamReader and StreamWriter. This is the final code without file access error:

```
public bool Load(string calendarEntriesFile)
{
    bool status = true;
    this.calendarEntriesFile = calendarEntriesFile; //store path for future use

    if (!File.Exists(calendarEntriesFile))
    {
        status = false;
        File.Create(calendarEntriesFile).Close(); //create the file as it do not exists
    }
    else
        FillList(); // File exists! :) then what are we waiting for lets read it .  .

    return status;
}

private void FillList()
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(calendarEntriesFile))
        {
            string line = rd.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)// read line by line in file all apointments
            {
                string[] data = line.Split('#');
                Row row = new Row();
                row.Adopt(data);//create a row of current line i.e appointment
                this.Add(row); // add it to the current list for display
                line = rd.ReadLine();
            }

            rd.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occured while reading the appointments File!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

public bool Save(string[] data)
{
    try
    {
        string line = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            line += data[i] + "#";
        }
        line = line.Remove(line.Length - 1);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(calendarEntriesFile, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
            writer.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tested this with some fake data and file access problem solved.