# CA2202 Do not dispose objects multiple times, How to Solve?

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

```
private string GetFileContent(string path)
{
    if(File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
    {
        FileStream fs=null;
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                fs.Flush();
                return tr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
             fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If FileStream fs is assigned to null code is running without warnings but I don't want to assign  filestream to null i.e., fs=null in using Statement.

So, what is the correct way of writing it without assigning null value?

Comment: Check the comments on Jon Skeet's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065168/does-disposing-streamreader-close-the-stream).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `try` / `finally`:

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        fs.Flush();
        return tr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

`using` is already doing something like this:

```
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    try
    {
        // code inside the `using` goes here
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And disposing will, by it's very nature, close the stream.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c-sharp) for more info about `using`.